# Visual c++ unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9@4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, directx

I have tried to find an answer for this for hours, and hours, and hours. This is frickin exhausting. In visual studio I keep having these library issues with DirectX and I think I have narrowed it down to a point where it is almost, almost solvable.

The error at compiling is in the title, here are images of some of my code and the dependencies and such:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a 32-bit build but you're linking to the 64-bit libs. If so, that's never going to work.

Comment: All I have are X86 and x64, should I link to X86?

Comment: h my god, I tried it and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Unresolved External Symbol is thrown if you are using a function defined in a header, in your case I think d3d9.h, but you haven't linked the containing implementation lib. Right click on your project name under solution explorer and than Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input, now on Additional Dependencies add your lib that I suppose it will be d3d9.lib or d3dx9.lib!